# Runtime error document not saved in excel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Getting run time error 1004 document not saved. When i click on debug it is going to activeworkbook.save code in my vb. Please help in handling this error in excel 2007.

Comment: Hi! Please provide some more information about this issue. Some code examples would be great.

Comment: I have worksheet_change function in which the following line of code is present.

Comment: Active workbook.save

Comment: Please edit your question and provide as much code as possible in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: A vbcode gets executed in this excel sheet when i click on a ActiveX button.. after some time i get a popup mentioning runtime error 1004: document not saved. And the macro gets stopped.